# How to receive a startup hex string during a debug session?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, serial, microchip, debugging

This is my setup:

I have a 'smart display' connected to the serial interface of a PCB with a PIC microcontroller. The PIC powers the smart display.
This smart display uses a boot mechanism.
When the power is on, the display start bootup. This process takes a few seconds.
At bootup, the  display sends a hex string to the serial interface.

I want to debug this serial interface using MPLAB X: I want to see the values of the received hex data.
However, during a debug session, it always hangs in an infinite while loop of an EUSART routine, waiting for data to receive.

I can't find a way to 'catch' this hex string during a debug session. Is there a way to receive hex string somehow?

Comment: why don't you use a serial terminal program to receive the serial data? ... it is unclear why you need to "debug" the data

Comment: I don't have the appropriate cable for connecting the display to the USB port at this moment.

Comment: I was thinking of UART connection as well to read from something like PuTTY. How about possibly an oscilloscope to capture byte readouts over serial interface? And if you say that you don’t have an oscilloscope, then perhaps you need to provide details on what equipment you do have.

Comment: Is the EUSART configured correctly? Are you sure there is data to receive? Can you receive data from the display at other times?

Comment: I have captured the byte readouts using an oscilloscope.The hex data looked fine. My PCB also has an LCD. However, it did not show the correct data when I wrote to it during a test.

Comment: Try finding some example code for the UART, also try receiving serial data from some other source, like a PC.   Make sure your serial settings match, also make sure you have considered the difference (not just voltage but *polarity*) between traditional logic-level UART signals and RS232.  Finally one has to be careful with a debugger not to disrupt the operation of the device, eg, you may want to set a breakpoint where a character (or better yet a newline terminated line of text) has been received, not inside or attempting to single step through the polling.

Comment: The baudrate of my PIC was different from my display. How stupid of me. I will check if the other serial settings match first.